# Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am trying to deploy my first Rails app using nginx and passenger on ubuntu.
Bundle install went fine and nginx starts. But I see the following error from passenger on the client side, "Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)"

In fact, I could see i18n-0.6.1 in the gem list.

I referred to many articles which tried to fix the same problem but didn't help me. Please let me know if you need any specific information.

Comment: Was this issue solved ?

Comment: Nope.I got this working on OS X as the back up solution. Still need to figure this out and appears to be a path issue.

Comment: I tried it without doing `yum update` on the host and installed an app and then performed gem install passenger on a non-default gemset. I dont know what worked, but its now working for me.